# Azure admin - &#39;No access to this subscription&#39; for Analyze costs

Tags: azure, cost-management, azure-cost-calculation

I am new to Azure, so I may have misunderstood something basic.

If I sign into the account and click on 'Cost Management' and then 'Analyze costs' I get this

[image: No Access]

If I click 'Find Owner' then 'View my access' I get

```
 Role = Service Administrator
 Description = Has full access to all resources in the subscription.
```

If I click on 'View my Access'  there is a drop down to enter my email address - it then confirms who I am, and once again says full access.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The cost analysis access denied issue was caused due to a recent deployment problem. The incident has been mitigated by reverting the deployment and then the issue was resolved.